# jQuery AJAX POSTs to action both hit the same callback method instead of their own

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

An interesting problem I have run into.  I have a Struts 2 web app where I use jquery AJAX calls within jquery UI dialogs to lookup data.  The same page has a couple different dialogs looking up different data.  Each dialog has paging, hence the "next" links shown below.  If I only have one dialog or multiple dialogs calling the same callback then everything works fine.  As soon as I have multiple dialogs, each calling their own callback to the action class then it breaks (meaning the getCustSearchHtml() method gets called in both AJAX calls below).  When I click on the Next link during a task-lookup, the right action method gets called but the success callback calls returnData.custSearchHtml instead of taskData.taskSearchHtml.  Here is the basic code:

```
$('#customer-lookup').delegate('#CLnextLink', 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var workOrderId = $("#workOrderId").val();
    var nextPage = $("#nextPage").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "CustomerLookup",
       data: { id: workOrderId, page: nextPage },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(returnData) {
          $("#customer-lookup").html(returnData.custSearchHtml);
       }
    });
});

$('#task-lookup').delegate('#TLnextLink', 'click', function(e) {
    var workOrderId = $("#workOrderId").val();
    var nextPage = $("#nextPage").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "TaskLookup",
       data: { id: workOrderId, page: nextPage },
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(taskData) {
          $("#task-lookup").html(taskData.taskSearchHtml);
       }
    });
    return false;
});

......

<div id="customer-lookup" class="ui-dialog" title="Customer Lookup">
    .....
        <a id="CLnextLink" href="#">Next Page</a>
    .....
</div>
<div id="task-lookup" class="ui-dialog" title="Task Lookup">
    .....
        <a id="TLnextLink" href="#">Next Page</a>
    .....
</div>
```

Anyone ever see this before or know what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You say "getCustSearchHtml()" gets called twice but there is no reference to that in the provided code.  This is a client side issue, drop all reference to struts2 from the question and the jquery ninja's I'm confident will find you an answer.

Comment: If you look at the ajax call for customer-lookup, the success callback sets the html from returnData.custSearchHtml.  That's the reference.  That gets called for the task-lookup as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple elements with the same id in your HTML. That is invalid and it will mess up jQuery in all sorts of ways.

EDIT:

you are still using the class selector .TLnextLink but TLnextLink is an ID

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I changed the code so the links have unique id's and still have the same issue.  I showed that change in the above code.

Comment: you are still using the class selector .TLnextLink but TLnextLink is an ID

Comment: Are you saying that the class and id can't be the same name?  If not, I am not following you.

Comment: Just tried changing everything to use id selectors.  Same problem.  Changed code above to reflect that.